# Read numbers from a list and create csv file with the columns that correspond to the numbers read

Tags: r, list, csv, cluster-computing

I have a dataset that is saved in a csv file called 'extremes' (30 columns and 2000 rows). I perform cluster analysis and I use capture.output to save the 
output in a csv file. Specifically, I do:

```
    capture.output(inf,file="Clusters.csv", append=TRUE)
```

where 'inf' is a function that returns the analysis output.'inf' is a list.

The output I save in the csv file (called 'Clusters.csv') is the following (as it appears in the R console):

```
$assign
 [1] 1 2 3 1 1 1 1 2 1 4 1 4 1 2 4 2 3 5 4 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

$list
$list$cluster.1
 [1]  1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30

$list$cluster.2
[1]  2  8 14 16 21 22 23

$list$cluster.3
[1]  3 17

$list$cluster.4
[1] 10 12 15 19

$list$cluster.5
[1] 18


$num
cluster.1 cluster.2 cluster.3 cluster.4 cluster.5 
   16         7         2         4         1
```

Based on the analysis, I also get a parameter called 'NumberClusters' which indicates the optimal number of clusters (for this particular dataset it takes the values of 2).

What I want to achieve is to read the specific columns from the csv file 'extremes' that make up the first cluster (i.e., 1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30) and save them in a  data.frame (and maybe store them in a csv file named 'Cluster1', then read the specific columns from the csv file 'extremes' that make up the second cluster (i.e., 2  8 14 16 21 22 23) and save them in a data.frame (and maybe in a csv file named 'Cluster2'). I can then continue my analysis using the two datasets 'Cluster1' and 'Cluster2'. 
My main problem, I think, is to find a way to read the columns that make up each cluster (e.g., for cluster 1, columns: 1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30) from the file 'Clusters.csv'. I believe that I will then  be able to read the data contained in these columns in file 'extremes.csv' using

```
read.xls("extremes.csv")[c(1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30])
```

I have also tried to work with the package 'xlsx' but didn't achieve anything.

Any help will be greatly appreciated because I have been stuck with this for some time now.

My data looks like this (this is a small sample; in fact I have 30 columns (financial indices) and 2019 rows (daily returns). I hope this helps.

```
Food    Beer    Smoke   Games   Books   Hshld   Clths
0.57    1.23    1.19    0.54    -0.19   0.31    0.52
0.48    0.57    -0.89   -0.23   -0.25   0.29    -0.26
-0.55   -0.75   -0.8    -0.41   -0.2    -0.29   -0.61
 0.6    -0.1    0.31    1.16    1.14    0.74    0.72
-0.44   -1.34   -1.73   -0.16   0.22    -0.97   -0.96
-0.25   -0.21   -0.07   -0.73   -0.4    -0.56   -0.8
0.11    -0.94   -0.3    -0.38   -0.07   -0.38   -0.24
-1.34   -2.12   -1.54   -1.52   -0.68   -1.72   -1.91
```

I run your code (your mock example) and I get

```
> cluster1
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

same for cluster2.

I then run the following using my dataset and get the same message (i.e., Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols).

```
output <- read.csv("Clusters.csv", header = TRUE)
output <- list()
cluster.data <- matrix(extremes, nrow = 2019, ncol = 30, byrow = TRUE) 
DT <- as.data.table(cluster.data)
cluster1 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster1), with = FALSE]
cluster1
cluster2 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster2), with = FALSE]
cluster2
```

I suspect that I got it completely wrong.

I run the code without output<-list(). That is:

**EDIT**: I think it is because we are not getting the `output$list$cluster2` name correct. Try `output$list$cluster.2`. I made changes to block below.  Please try:

```
output <- read.csv("Clusters.csv", header = TRUE)
# take a look at output
output

cluster.data <- matrix(extremes, nrow = 2019, ncol = 30, byrow = TRUE) 
DT <- as.data.table(cluster.data)
cluster1 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster.1), with = FALSE]
cluster1
cluster2 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster.2), with = FALSE]
cluster2
```

edit: We are nearly there! Please try print out `output` and `output$list$cluster.1` and also `str(output$list$cluster.2)` to see how it is classed. Finally, if this does not work use `dput` on `output` to a file and look at it in Notepad/text editor. dput writes data into R commands to recreate. Post it so we can check output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a bit tricky without your data block. Please take a look at the `data.table` [cheatsheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) if you are unfamiliar with this package.

Assuming your columns are standard so don't have names V1 V2. Lets isolate your two blocks so you can save them down.

```
library(data.table)

# mini mockup example using just first 5 columns
output <- list()
output$list$cluster.1 <- c(1,4,5)
output$list$cluster.2 <- c(2)
# EDIT: Kostas you would do this with your data
#  "output I save in the csv file (called 'Clusters.csv')"
# get the output structure back
# output <- read.csv("Clusters.csv", header = TRUE)
# Then the code will read your list results

# mockup of your data using a to e so we can see how columns selected
#   its simply two lines of repeated a b c d e
cluster.data <- matrix(letters[1:5], nrow = 2, ncol = 5, byrow = TRUE) 

#assuming you want the column names will just be default V1 V2...
#  cluster 1 we would expect it to look like this
#  headings     V1 V4 V5
#  data         a d e 
#  data line 2  a d e 


# turn it into a data.table
#   you would read your data in as csv 
#   data <- as.data.table(read.csv("yourfile.csv")) etc.
DT <- as.data.table(cluster.data)

# subset data to cluster 1
cluster1 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster.1), with = FALSE]

   V1 V4 V5
1:  a  d  e
2:  a  d  e

# likewise for 2
cluster2 <- DT[, c(output$list$cluster.2), with = FALSE]

   V2
1:  b
2:  b
```

Note I am using `with = FALSE` in data.table so that the 4th column and not column called 4 is called.

You would then save these blocks down. See 'write.table' or 'write.csv'. Type `?write.table` at prompt to get help.

You can "parameterize" for different cluster lengths using:
`as.name(paste0("cluster.", as.character(i)))` to get cluster.3 when i = 3

Hope this helps!

**LATER EDIT**: Kostas I see your data from output is now called cluster.1 not cluster1 as I originally had so I have edited my code above. `$list$cluster.1`

Comment: Thanks micstr. The problem remains in the sense that you don't take the columns straight from my outcome. In your example                                                                                                            output$list$cluster1 <- c(1,4,5)
you manually ask for columns 1, 4 and 5, while I want to do is to read from my output the order of the columns in a cluster and then save these in a separate file. Other than that your code works fine.

Comment: No problem. I dont have your data so I had to mockup it up. I will edit to show you how to get this from your data, as I understand it.

Comment: I have added a sample of my data below my question

Comment: The with = FALSE works on the column number, so you dont need to worry about the labelling. Is this code now working ok?

Comment: I am totally confused now. Maybe I need to think about it more carefully. I add what I did below my question.

Comment: Kostas - please remove output <- list() it makes the list empty. I just used it to set up a list container. You don't need it. Then look at output$list$cluster1 and see if it is the 1,4,5 , ... numbers you are expecting.

Comment: I run your code with the mock example (see below my answer) and I get the message 'Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)' for both cluster 1 and cluster2.

Comment: if I could read the order of columns fthat make up cluster1 that is contained in the file 'Clusters' I could then get the data for the clusters by using cluster1<-read.csv(file="extremes.csv",header=TRUE)[c(1,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)]. The problem is that I cannot read  the numbers 1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 contained in Clusters.csv file under $list$cluster.1, and then form c(1,4,5,6,7,9,11,13,20,24,25,26,27,28,29,30)]

Comment: Thanks for the help micstr. You code runs fine for the case of your example. However I haven't managed to modify it to work in my case. The problem is that you define manually the columns that make up the clusters. For example, you define cluster1 to be columns 1, 4, and 5 using "output$list$cluster.1 <- c(1,4,5)". What I want to R to do is to read the columns that make up cluster1 from the file 'Clusters' where I have saved the output of my analysis, which can be found at the first part of my initial question above. So every time I need different columns I would have to manually enter them.

Comment: Kostas, please look at my edit. I am trying to read in your output structure list so we can get the columns from that with every run. From your output these are stored in  `$list$cluster.1`. See output <- read.csv("Clusters.csv", header = TRUE). I think you want to save your cluster analysis output as a RDS file not csv so you can reload and more easily access the list. Perhaps you can just get from *inf* right away. So does `inf$list$cluster.1` give you columns you want straight after running your cluster analysis?

Comment: Thanks for your patience micstr. You are right, using inf$list$cluster.1 returns the columns that make up the clusters. e.g., for cluster1: [1]  1  4  5  6  7  9 11 13 20 24 25 26 27 28 29 30. I can then use `cluster1<-read.csv(file="extremes.csv", header=TRUE)[c(inf$list$cluster.1)]`, and `write.table(cluster1,file="cluster1.csv",sep=',',row.names=FALSE,col.names=TRUE)` to save the columns in a seperate csv file. You also mentioned that I can parameterize for different number of optimal clusters ( given by 'NumberClusters' in my code). I'll try this as well and let you know. Many thanks